# In ruby on rails how to encrypt data and store in database

Tags: mysql, encryption, ruby-on-rails-5, attr-encrypted, lockbox-2

**I am using rails v 5.1.7 and ruby v 2.6.3
i need to encrypt data like mobile number at db level
how to achieve this, any gem suggestion to use**

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this gem for encryption data store in database column

https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted